# Running destroy_all on an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I run `destroy_all` on an array?

I've got the follow query:

```
spam_users = User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ~* '21cn.com'")
```

I've tried running `spam_users.destroy_all` but I get `undefined method 'destroy_all' for #<Array:0x10b09ce30>`.

I'm running Rails 2.3.8 in this particular app along with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't execute [`destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) on an array, `destroy_all` is a class method on your models. The following should kill off everything would be in your `spam_users` array:

```
User.destroy_all("email ~* '21cn.com'")
```

You could also iterate over `spam_users` and destroy them one by one if you already had them for other purposes:

```
spam_users.each(&:destroy)
```

You might want to adjust your regex a bit as well:

```
User.destroy_all("email ~* '21cn\\.com$'")
```

so that you're looking for a literal `.` rather than "any character" and anchor it to the end of the string. You could also use a `%q(...)` quoted string to reduce the escaping:

```
User.destroy_all(%q(email ~* '21cn\.com$'))
```